# How to get Item View by position in GridView (in onCreateView )?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I would like to get **the item view by position in a GridView**, and I don't know how to do it.

I have tried to iterate over **gridView.getChildCount()**, but it returns 0 ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/8944678/1788704 ).

When I call **gridView.getCount()**, it returns 25 (the exact number of Items of my gridview).

When I try to call **getChildAt(position)** in the loop with getCount, I get a NPE.

What I want to do exactly is to get the item view to get 2 ImageView inside the item view and set a **setOnClickListener()**  on each of them.

At the moment, I set these listeners in the **setOnItemClickListener()** of the gridView.

But the first time I click on my imageViews, the listener is not set, then it is okay (as it is initialized once the cell is clicked).

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          [... ... ...]

          gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                ImageView shutterDown = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_shutter_down);
                shutterDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

                ImageView shutterUp = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_shutter_up);
                shutterUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

// The rest of the onItemClickListener (normal behavior).
            }
        });
    return rootView;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my grid cell :
[image: Grid cell]

Comment: I usually do this kind of thing in a custom adapter. Just extend BaseAdapter `getView()` and put your `onClicks()` in there

Comment: I have my own adapter... and I'm stupid. I didn't want to use it before because I have to create a thread (socket inside) in my onClicks, but with an AsyncTask it should be alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

gridView.getCount() is the size of your adapter, so you have 25 items in the adapter

gridView.getChildCount() is the size of the children of the grid, so the grid has no children when you call this, so in this time you probably hasn't been draw on screen yet.

That's why you get a NPE because you have no child view to get.